# Override parent :hover on child :hover

Tags: css, hover, css-selectors

I have two child elements which I set as hidden by default.

```
.child1, .child2{
visibility:hidden;
}

#parent :hover .child1, #parent:hover .child2{
visibility:visible;
}
```

As you can see, whenever I hover the parent, the children become visible. So far so easy.

Now here's the tricky part: When I hover over one of the children, I'd like all the other children to become hidden again. So when I hover over child1, child2 should not be visible anymore. I want to 'undo' the hovering of the parent, so to speak, and only leave the child visible over which I am hovering.

How do I override or undo the parent:hover ?

**Edit:** 
I found this, which is going in the right direction:

```
#parent:hover > .child1:hover{
    do something;
}
```

Basically, when both the parent AND child1 are hovered, then the style applies to child1. This is what I'm looking for, but now the problem is, how do I apply the style to child2 instead of child1?

**Edit2:**
Another idea would be to use something like this:

```
#parent:hover >.children:not(.child1){
    do something;
}
```

This selects all children of the parent which are not child1 and applies the style to them. And again, a problem: This is only triggered when hovering the parent alone. How can I trigger this exact same effect when the parent AND child1 are hovered?

Comment: Not with CSS. You cannot select parent elements or previous siblings with CSS(3).

Comment: This will select .child elements but only the ones after the currently hovered .child `#parent:hover .child:hover ~ .child {`

Comment: onMouseOver is only applied if there is no other element 'higher' than the one you are pointing at, so you only hover one element at once. Isn't there a way to make the css :hover behave that way? Only hover one element at a time?

Comment: If all non-hovered children are hidden, how would you hover over any child to make it visible?

Comment: The children are 'inside' the parent element. Whilst hovering the parent, the children are visible. So I hover over a visible child and keep that child visible.

Comment: So you're saying that once the cursor moves off a child and onto the parent, all children should re-appear?

Comment: Exactly. Basically I want the parent to 'not' be hovered while I'm hovering a child.

Comment: @Andy That's exactly what I'd need, but applying to all siblings instead of just the following ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, since there didn't seem to be a proper way to do exactly what I wanted, I used a bit of a work-around and solved it using the opacity:

```
.child1, .child2{ 
    opacity:0; 
}

#parent:hover .child1, 
#parent:hover .child2{ 
    opacity:0.6; 
}

#parent:hover > .child1:hover,
#parent:hover > .child2:hover{
    opacity:1; 
}
```

So basically, when I hover the parent alone, all children are 'semi-transparent', and when I hover the parent AND a child, that child becomes fully visible. It's a bit different than the original idea, but it turned out okay.